# Are lockpicks in ESO one-use only?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

I just recently picked up ESO a few weeks ago during the free-to-play time. I'm enjoying it but I am/was having problems with picking locks.

So I started looking at the tutorials for advice, and they all suggest that you can use lockpicks over and over again until they break. But in practice, it seems that every time I try to open a chest I lose a lockpick. They are not breaking. They just aren't in my inventory anymore.

So was there a recent-ish change where whether you succeed or fail, each attempt to open a chest uses up a lockpick? Or is my character somehow bugged?

If it makes a difference, I'm playing on a PS4 with the Elsweyr collectors edition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's completely normal. Lockpicks in the game are a consumable considered a currency you pay to open locks. Failed attempts cost additional lockpicks by destroying the one in use.

It's not 100% realistic, but consider it wear and tear. Don't worry too much about them, even if you've got a shortage. Over time you'll get far more lockpicks than you'll ever be able to use from looting alone.